# Independence of infinitely many random variables

Tags: probability-theory, infinity

I was reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) wiki article about probabilistic independence, it says

> An infinite family of σ-algebras is said to be independent if all its **finite** subfamilies are independent.

So when we say a set of countably infinitely many random variables is mutually independent, what we really mean is any of its **finite** subset is mutually independent. My question is, what's preventing us from dropping the modifier **"finite"** here? Does it make sense if one would want to extend the definition to include infinite subsets/subfamilies? I was told it definitely **doesn't**, if you assume the axiom of choice. How come?

Comment: If you drop 'finite' in the definition it makes no sense. You are not even defining independence of an infinite set of r.v.'s. However, it is a fact that if a family is independent so is any subfamily.

Comment: If we drop the word **finite** here then what's left is not a *definition*. This because any family is a subfamily of itself. It turns into the *statement* that all subfamilies of infinite and independent $\sigma$-algebras are independent.

Comment: Correct me if I'm mistaken, but I believe your question is why we can't define independence for an infinite family of $\sigma$-algebras $(\tau_i)_{i \in \mathcal I}$ for some index set $\mathcal I$ by the property $\mathbb{P}(\bigcap_{i \in \mathcal I} A_i) = \bigcap_{i \in \mathcal I} \mathbb{P}(A_i)$ for every collection of sets $(A_i)_{i \in \mathcal I}$?  If so, I'm not sure I understand the issues the previous commentors are pointing out.  If $\mathcal I$ is uncountable, this can definitely cause problems, but I don't immediately see any obvious problems if $\mathcal I$ is countable.

Comment: @user6247850 That's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a countable family of $\sigma$-algebras, the definitions are equivalent.  More precisely, let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(\tau_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a family of sub $\sigma$-algebras of $\mathcal F$.  Then every finite sub-family is independent iff we have $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_i\right) = \prod_{i=1}^\infty \mathbb{P}(A_i)$ for every collection of sets $(A_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $A_i \in \tau_i$ for all $i$.  This property clearly implies independence of any finite sub-family (take $A_i = \Omega$ if $\tau_i$ is not in the sub-family), and the reverse implication follows directly from the monotone convergence theorem for sets.

In the case that we have an uncountable family of $\sigma$-algebras $(\tau_i)_{i \in \mathcal I}$, it is not obvious how to define $\prod_{i \in \mathcal I} \mathbb{P}(A_i)$ when $\mathcal I$ is uncountable.  However, since $\mathbb{P}(A) \in [0,1]$ for all $A$, a reasonable definition might be \begin{align*}
\prod_{i \in \mathcal I} \mathbb{P}(A_i) &:= \inf_{\substack{F \subset \mathcal I \\ F \text{ finite}}} \prod_{i \in F} \mathbb{P}(A_i).
\end{align*}
In this case, the property $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i\in \mathcal I} A_i\right) = \prod_{i\in \mathcal I} \mathbb{P}(A_i)$ for every collection of sets $A_i \in \tau_i$ is not equivalent to every finite sub-family of $(\tau_i)$ being independent.  For starters, since $\mathcal I$ is uncountable, there is no guarantee that $\bigcap_{i\in \mathcal I} A_i$ is even measurable.  Even if we tried to change the property to "$\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i\in \mathcal I} A_i\right) = \prod_{i\in \mathcal I} \mathbb{P}(A_i)$ for every collection of sets $A_i \in \tau_i$ such that $\bigcap_{i \in \mathcal I} A_i$ is measurable," it still would not be equivalent.

For example, take $\Omega = [0,1]$ with $\mathbb{P}$ being Lebesgue measure.  Let $\mathcal I := [0,1]$ and $\tau_x := \{\emptyset,\Omega,\{x\},(\Omega \setminus \{x\})\}$ for all $x \in \mathcal I$.  Since $\mathbb{P}(A_x) \in \{0,1\}$ for every $A_x \in \tau_x$, any finite sub-family of $(\tau_x)_{x \in \mathcal I}$ is independent.  However, if we take $A_x := \Omega \setminus \{x\}$, then $\prod_{x \in \mathcal I} \mathbb{P}(A_i) = 1$ but $\bigcap_{x \in \mathcal I} A_x = \emptyset$ so $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{x\in \mathcal I} A_x\right) = 0 \ne \prod_{x \in \mathcal I} \mathbb{P}(A_i)$.